# Ordering of English sound changes in verbal morphology

Tags: verbs, history, morphology, phonology

As we all know, the Early Modern English 3sg verbal ending *-eth* has become *-s* in Modern English. This presumably happened in two steps:

1. Elision of the unstressed *e* in the final syllable
2. Changing final *-th* to *-s*.

But do we know **what order** these changes happen in? Do we find intermediate forms like *speak'th* (with elided vowel but no consonant change) or *speakes* (with consonant change but the vowel preserved)?

Comment: I can’t find any historical occurrences of forms like *speak’th*.  Forms like *speakes* certainly occur reasonably frequently; but it’s not clear whether this is actually the intermediate form you’re after, or just the modern *-s* construction applied by writers who spelled the base verb as *speake*.  One could eliminate this issue by using a verb which wasn’t archaically spelled with an extra *-e*, but I can’t think of any such verb right now… can anybody else?

Comment: I don't know... but I was under the impression that -th already existed as an allomorph of -eth, and that -(e)s replaced both allomorphs at once; some articles I read say that "-(e)s replaced -(e)th", rather than describing a development in two stages. Another possibility is that both changes happened for a large part simultaneously: I know the introduction of the s took rather a long time, and both forms probably coexisted for centuries, -(e)th gradually being pushed back into more formal usage.

Comment: http://www.bartleby.com/211/1905.html

Comment: See also: Bryson's _[The Mother Tongue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mother_Tongue_(book))_ for a quick-and-dirty history on morphology.

Comment: @Hal: but don't trust it. Bryson's an entertaining writer, but he's a journalist, not a linguist, and *The Mother Tongue* is full of errors and half-truths.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Good to know. Some of his research did seem apocryphal, but I could see where he was going with it.

Answer (score 2):

In Old English, a final *-th* without a vowel before was attested in the conjugation of 3p. sg. verbs. For example, the verb, *steal* was *stilð* in the 3p. sg.

This also occurred in words such as *heal* (with *hǣlþ*) and say (with *segð*).

In these words, it is easy to see how a final *þ* and *ð* could become alveolarized as /s/ and /z/, respectively.

This means that in these words the final unstressed e had already been elided. From this, we know that the order of events, at least in these words, are as you listed: fisrt the elision of the e, and then the change from *-th* to *-s*.

Comment: What evidence do we have that there was ever an *e* in those words?